# am trying to hide scrollbar from angular material sidenav

Tags: angular, angular-material

am trying to hide the scrollbar from the side while keeping the ability to scroll

StackBlitz Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-443roq

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-443roq-d1fsdm) to do this kind of things, best way to open developer console and find inspected element then override css on this element in style.css if it is 3rd party library. For your situation, your scroll element is `mat-drawer-inner-container` then to hide it use `webkit-scrollbar` pseudo code.
 put below code in style.css

```
.mat-drawer-inner-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Did u put in style css ? check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-443roq-d1fsdm

Comment: i did now and it worked thx , but why it didn't work when i put the code in the component it self.

Comment: Because  if you open developer console you inspesct any element in css part you will see that they have suffix like [_ngcontent-qll-c1] it means every component create own style type. But 3rd party libraries doesn't put this suffix so css cant find this css rule in component css because it search with suffix. But in style css rules apply every components also. So you need to write in style css generally in style.css if they dont create custom classes

Comment: It did not work for me I dont know why please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72747895/angular-mat-sidenav-does-not-change-scroll-style

Comment: Worked like a charm. Add the above code in style.css

Answer (score 4):

In my case (Angular 13 )
code :

```
.mat-drawer-inner-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
display: none;
```

}

have to be used in **styles.scss** , no effect if used in app.component.scss

Answer (score 0):

@jhon response dont work for me (mozilla firefox browser) the demo exemple dont work neither (but work on chrome)
the way i implemented it was like this :
(thanks to [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62692305/setting-the-css-overflow-property-to-hidden-on-only-one-specific-component-in-an) )

add a tag to your sidenav:

```
<mat-sidenav-container>

<mat-sidenav #sidenav class="mat-elevation-z8" [mode]="sidebarMode" [opened]="sidebarIsOpen">
    <mat-nav-list>
        // your list for sidenav
    </mat-nav-list>

//rest of the code
```

notify the need of `#sidenav`

then in your template component :

```
import { AfterViewInit, Renderer2, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSidenav } from '@angular/material/sidenav';

export class Template implements ...<other-implements> AfterViewInit{

@ViewChild('sidenav')
sidenav!: MatSideNav


...someCode...

ngAfterViewInit(): void {

    this.renderer.setStyle(this.sidenav._content.nativeElement,  'scrollbar-width', 'none')
  }
```