# Setting the CSS overflow property to hidden on only one specific component in Angular

Tags: css, angular, frontend, overflow

I try to set the "overflow-y: hidden" on a specific component in Angular but it won't work and I can only apply it to the "body" element which ends up applying it to all components and cause problems.

How can I apply it to only one specific component? thanks

Comment: Can you provide some code you try, and the expected result?

Comment: I want to set this for only my login component, so in CSS file specified for this component and the first div wrapper which has class login: .login {
    height: 65vh;
    padding-right: 0;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}                                                                                                                                        But this won't apply this overflow change. When I set this property to the body element in general style.css it will work but It would affect all the components.

Comment: It is still rather unclear for me. Your code or minimum working example would be nice. For now, I see that you try to apply styles for .login selector. It is a class selector, not component.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YFLopqh8LOQx-o1OEycuRK3E6Y8lqBpO/view               sorry I could not explain clearly. this is how the login looks like. do you have any opinion on how to get rid of that scroll bar?

Comment: check out this one too. tried to explain more clearly   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M_dsBm4HN0HeztG32puMhM_ujqgIumSY/view?usp=sharing

Comment: For now, I see your expected result. But did not get your specific try as a code(you can paste your snippets here). Also, you can try one of provided answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the selector of the component in css.

```
Ts:
    @Component({
      selector: 'example-component',
    ...
    })

Css:    
      example-component {

    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a property:  `currentUrl: String;`

Create a function layout() that gives you the current url of a component as follows and you may run it in app.component.ts file:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
constructor(private router: Router)

navigate(route: string) {
    console.log(route);
    this.router.navigate([route]);
  }

layout() {
    this.router.events.forEach((event) => {
      if (event['url'] != undefined)
        this.currentUrl = event['url'];
      console.log(this.currentUrl)
    });
  }
```

And in the app.component file add a div class to your router-outlet and bind your css class through ngClass as follows:

```
<div [ngClass]="{ 'HideScroll':currentUrl == '/login' }">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
```

And in app.component.css, you can add your specific styling to HideScroll class as follows:

```
.HideScroll{
    overflow-y: hidden    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Find Complete Working Demo in this [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-32hrsn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhide-scrollbar-y.directive.ts)

For your use-case you can create directive to hide scrollbar. You just need to reference custom directive to your login component parent element to see effect. In Above code-link You can see Angular Router example. Default Login-component is loaded, when you changed URL to /home - new home component is loaded and scrollbar is back.

so For example.. this is template of Login Component.

```
<main appHideScrollbarY>
    ...
</main>
```

Above, we set `appHideScrollbarY` directive to login-component template to hide `scrollbarY`.

Now, see code for `appHideScrollbarY`...

```
import { Directive, Renderer2, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';


@Directive({
   selector: '[appHideScrollbarY]'
})
export class HideScrollbarYDirective {
   abc: string  = 'hello';
   constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private element: ElementRef,
               @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {}

   ngAfterViewInit(){
       this.renderer.setStyle(this.element.nativeElement.offsetParent, 'height', 'auto !important');
       this.renderer.setStyle(this.element.nativeElement.offsetParent, 'overflow-y', 'hidden');  
   }
   ngOnDestroy(){
       this.renderer.removeStyle(this.document.body, 'overflow-y');
   }
}
```

Now, When you change URL from `/home` scrollbar-y is back.